# Linq to entities custom function in select

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

In Linq to Entities one can't use standard c# method to modify the results in the "select" clause, canonical functions are required.

I need to invoke such query:

```
CoreEntities.Contracts.Select(
c=> new {
   c.Name,
   c.Type,
   Role = MapToRole(c));

private string MapToRole(Contract contract) {
    switch(contract.Type) {
        case: CTypes.Main: return "somerole1";break;
        case: CTypes.Secondary: return "somerole2";break;
        // ... 
        default: break;
    }

    return "none";
}
```

The "MapToRole" is a C# method created just to declutter the linq query.

Is there a way to create a custom c# function that would be accepted by Entity Framework "linq to Entity" parser?

I've found a solution for query filters but not for data formatting.

Comment: Could you add your MapToRole method to the question?

Comment: In MapToRole there are simple if/else/switch statements.

Comment: If you can convert MapToRole to a lamba expression, (use conditional operator, etc.) then you could use LINQKit to map the lambda into the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that as it's a simple transformation, there's no reason this needs to be translated by the provider.  I would suggest simply adding `AsEnumerable()` before your `Select()` to "detach" your projection from the provider.

Alternatively you could have a `CTypes` property in your data type and a method/property that performs the transformation of that within your model.

---

As a side note, doing this particular transformation in your application layer means that you're only pulling through the enum value, not a string - therefore less data from the provider.

Comment: Adding CTypes property to my model causes raising the Linq to entity exception. Additionally the property is being mapped using AutoMapper to another model.

Comment: My calling the function in select or calling `AsEnumerable` before the transformation, you cause EF to retrieve the entire row. Ideally, there's be a way to retrieve just the columns asked for in the anonymous object, with the transformation converted to SQL.

Comment: @EdwardBrey That's very easy to do, simply project the fields that you're interested in to an anonymous type using `.Select()` prior to the `.AsEnumerable` call and this will ensure only the fields you need are queried from the provider.